# What is wrong with this printing function in my java code?

Tags: java, fixed

My problem is fixed, thanks guys !

So i'm working on a school project that i thought should be written in C but it turns out i had to do it in java, now i managed to make it work somehow but the result i'm getting isn't what i want it to be. If anyone could take a look and tell me why the result is wrong that would be appreciated !

My Java code :

```
public static void printMatrix(int p[][], int n){
               int i, j;
               for ( i=0;i<n;i++){
                   for (j=0;j<3;j++){
                       if (p[i][j]==0) System.out.println(".\t");
                       else System.out.println(p[i][j]+"\t");
                   }
               }

               System.out.println("-------------------");
           }
```

My working C code :

```
void printMatrix(int **p, int n){
    int i, j;
    printf("\n\n");
    for (i=0 ; i<n ; i++){
            for (j=0 ; j<3 ; j++){
                if (p[i][j] == 0) printf(".\t");
                else printf("%d\t", p[i][j]);
            }
            printf("\n");
      }
    printf("-------------------");
}
```

the result i'm getting :

```
1   
1   
.   

2   
2   
.   

3   
3   
.   
-------------------
```

the result i'm looking for :

```
1       .       .   
2       .       .   
3       .       .   
-------------------
```

Comment: What result are you getting?

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer, i just added the result i'm getting to the post ! :)

Comment: Problem you are getting may be in println. This method prints output and a new line

Comment: @FredLarson I've deleted my thank you post, thanks for the tip but i actually need 15+ rep to upvote an answer so i thought i would thank everyone before i leave. :)

Comment: It's usually tolerated to thank people in comments, even though [this is not encouraged](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/258004/10077). You should be able to accept an answer after a delay.

Answer (score 2):

`print()` and `println()` are different methods: `println()` adds line break.

```
public static void printMatrix(int p[][], int n){
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++){
             if (p[i][j] == 0) 
                 System.out.print(".\t");
             else 
                 System.out.print(p[i][j]+"\t");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    System.out.println("-------------------");
}
```

Comment: Rather than sending a call to println(); I would send a call to print("\n"). They are the same thing, however println(); prints an empty string then a new line character, whereas print("\n") just prints a newline character.

Comment: Than you for your answer, i cannot upvote since i don't have +15 rep yet, so i wanted to properly thank you at least ! :)

Comment: @CraigParkinson not exactly right. `println()` just puts a line separator into a stream, no additional empty string is putted there. Look at the source code.

Answer (score 2):

`System.out.println(str)` prints a newline after `str`. Use `System.out.print(str)` instead.